# Reference Excel cells in Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-formula

Does anyone know of a pre-packaged solution for referencing Excel cells directly in a Word document?

For example,

> ```
>                                                          {[TestExcel]Tab1!A1}
> ```
>
> Dear Mr. {[TestExcel]Tab1!A2},
>
> Our systems have alerted us that your account {TestExcel]Tab1!AccountNumber} is overdue. Please remit payment of {TestExcel]Tab1!PaymentDue} immediately.

This example uses a hypothetical { } syntax, where the contents are standard Excel formula.

Every solution I've seen uses custom VBA to accomplish this. It seems like an extremely common need for which there should be some good 3rd party software available that lets non-technical users accomplish this task.

As indicated in the example above both named ranges and standard cell references would need to be supported.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.

Step 1: Copy the excel cell.

Step 2: Go to your word document where you want to paste the reference.

Step 3: Right click

Step 4: Under paste options, select  "link with source formatting" or "link and merge formatting".

Comment: Thanks. It's amazing how every Google result I found involved writing VBA.

Comment: If I want to insert the value inline with my word text, say I want to simply have the 38 from Excel in my Word sentence "He's 38 years old." witihin a text, I have the problem that at the very least I get a Newline along with the imported 38 that I cannot remove (I can temporarily remove it, but as soon as I "Update" the object in Word, Newline or formatting comes back. Any clue?

Comment: Is there a solution to @FlorianH 's comment in regard to the unwanted linebreak that gets inserted as well?

Answer (score 4):

I tried @Green Demon's method, but the two Paste Options listed were not present for me (Office 2013). I only had Keep Source Formatting, Merge Formatting, and Keep Text Only. However, I poked around and found the Paste Special, which was hidden on the Ribbon

The instructions are as follows:

1. Copy the Excel range.
2. Go to your Word document, and **left** click where you want to paste the Excel range.
3. Click on Paste Special from the Ribbon as shown below, or type <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+V</kbd>.

[image: Location of Paste Special on the Word 2013 Ribbon]

4. Click on the Paste link radio button.
5. Click on Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object. The Paste Special dialog box should look something like this:

[image: Paste Special Dialog Box]

6. Click OK.

The range should now be pasted in your document, and if you save, close, and re-open the Word document, you will be prompted about whether or not you want to "update this document with the data from the linked files," which works the same way as it does if you're doing Excel-to-Excel linking.

This feature is fantastic, and I'm so happy to have found it today. However, in my brief experience using it, having these Word-to-Excel links dramatically increases the amount of time it takes to open your Word document, even before it prompts you about updating. After that, the act of updating the Excel links takes much longer than it would if you were doing the same linking Excel-to-Excel. All of my work is done on network-share files, so YMMV.

Comment: This is also what for me on Office 2010.

Answer (score 3):

While Will's solution indeed links from the Cell objet, the content is inserted as a picture.

In the same dialog, selecting "Unformatted Unicode Text" instead will link and insert only the cell's content, which is desirable if you apply custom formatting on your text.

Unfortunately, this action only works for a single cell. Copying multiple cells will result in a text block with individual cell content seperated by tabs or line skip, with the entire block considered linked and entire. The solution is to link individual cells using this method.

This can become tedious if you plan on linking large portions of table from Excel, as for every cell the dialog must be invoked. It can be sped up by using hotkeys, but the sequence gets tedious:

<kbd>alt</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd>, then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>,  <kbd>↓</kbd>, and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Obviously this is not practial for large numbers of cells. A AutoHotkey script can help but it third party grafted solution, on par with using VBA scripts.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> works too. If you're building big documents clicking the ribbon every time gets murderous after a while.

Answer (score 1):

As this is still a problem but the other answers do not take into account the latest development in word, there is a new solution, editing Green Demons answer:

Step 1: Copy the excel cell.

Step 2: Go to your word document where you want to paste the reference.

Step 3: go to the "home" tab

Step 4: Under paste options, go to "Paste Special", click on "paste link", click on "Unformatted Text".

This solves the issue others were having with the new lines that you would otherwise have with just Green Demons' solution.

Hope this still helps others.