# How to link two Excel sheets in MS Word Mail Merge?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I have two Excel Sheets, Attendance.xlsx & Marks.xlsx, having two different data. And, I have a Word file, in which I am creating a Letter with fixed template using Mail Merge option.

> I am not able to link those Excel sheet values into the word file. I can select only one sheet's data at any time.

Kindly let me know how to solve the problem, without copy pasting the data into one sheet.

Comment: Word's mail merge can link to only one data source -there's no way to change or work around that. You'll need to find some way to combine the information from the two sheets into one sheet. If you were using a database I'd say create a query for the purpose. I believe there is a function in Excel that can do something similar, but I can't remember its name... But in any case, this sounds like a one-to-many situation, which is also something Word doesn't handle simply. What is it you intend to do with "Marks" data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371442/reference-excel-cells-in-word

Answer (score -1):

A mailmerge can only reference one data source at a time. In the case of an Excel workbook, for example, that means a single worksheet. However, a mailmerge main document can contain DATABASE fields and each DATABASE field can reference whatever datasource you want it to. A more detailed outline of the process can be found at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/mail-merge-to-a-word-table-on-a-single-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103 . For a working demonstration of a mailmerge referencing one worksheet in an Excel data source and a DATABASE field referencing a different worksheet, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/37844-mail-merge-using-one-excel-file-multiple.html. The same technique can be extended to referencing worksheets in different workbooks.